# Next JS 14 - Use Client api headers

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

```
"use client";
import { paths } from "../../types/generated-types";
import createClient from "openapi-fetch";

const baseUrl = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL;

const getHeaders = () => {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    const sesToken = sessionStorage.getItem("acce") || "";
    const idToken = sessionStorage.getItem("token") || "";
    const refreshToken = sessionStorage.getItem("token") || "";

    return {
      accessToken: sesToken,
      refreshToken: refreshToken,
      idToken: idToken,
    };
  }

  return {};
};

const client = createClient<paths>({ baseUrl, headers: getHeaders() });

export const GET = client.GET;
export const PUT = client.PUT;
export const POST = client.POST;
export const PATCH = client.PATCH;
export const DELETE = client.DELETE;
```

Im having issues with NextJS 14 and openapi-fetch assigning headers to the fetch call from some pages. I use this inside "use client" components. but sometimes it sends empty headers unless I refresh the page.

typeof window !== "undefined"

if the call is inside a client component the window should exists

any idea if there is a better way? I have a server version where it uses cookies